# Getting the Hash in MD5 Powershell

Tags: powershell, hash

I am trying to make a script that can get the hash MD5 of Files and Directories that I get with the function ChildItem. My Script at the moment is the following. Why is the part of the Hash not working?

```
 $UserInput = Read-Host



 Get-ChildItem -Path $UserInput -Recurse  


function md5hash($UserInput)
{
    $fullPath = Resolve-Path $UserInput
    $md5 = new-object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    $file = [System.IO.File]::Open($fullPath,[System.IO.Filemode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)
    [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash($file))
    $file.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: No need to create your own function. Just use `Get-FileHash`.

Comment: You're never actually calling your md5hash function?

Comment: I do after the code I wrote with md5hash but it just won't work with the $UserInput variable

Comment: @Bill_Stewart:  If he is still on PowerShell 2 or 3, he needs to write his own.  I always write to 2 standard just in case I run across 2K8 servers without management framework upgrades.

Comment: Aware, actually did that a while back: [Calculate MD5 and SHA1 File Hashes Using PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/calculate-md5-and-sha1-file-hashes-using-powershell). OP did not mention version, so I assume up-to-date.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart:  Funny thing is, he's using Resolve-Path which I don't think was introduced until PoSh v4 so he should have access to Get-FileHash...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a one-liner:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -Recurse -File | Get-Filehash -Algorithm MD5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$someFilePath = "C:\foo.txt"
$md5 = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
$hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($someFilePath)))
```

Edit:  Your code should work fine and even better than what I proposed as my example is limited to files < 2GB in size.  Since yours uses a Stream, it's more efficient (doesn't load it all into memory first), and won't have the size limitation.

Your file path must be a file since you're making I/O calls specific to files...

Comment: But I am using "[System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)" so I guess that is reading it, right? Or maybe the path that I am giving is of a directory, but it should give a MD5 anyways, right?

Comment: .ComputeHash() does accept a FileStream so what you have will work -- ma bad.

Comment: If the path is a directory, then yes, that's a problem.  If you look at the IO calls, you're specifying a file:  System.IO.File::Open()